# Determine php major from php version

Tags: php

I have an array `$cfg=Array('5.3', '5.4')` which contains major Php versions. I want to determine major from version. For example if input is *5.4.10-1ubuntu3* the response should be *5.4*. My code is this:

```
 foreach ($cfg as $key => $phpMajor) {
    if (version_compare($phpVersion, $phpMajor, '>=') and version_compare($phpVersion, $cfg[$key+1], '<')) {
        var_dump($phpMajor);
    }

}
```

But this is not  cover my all possibilities.
Can you help me please?

Comment: http://php.net/phpversion  Example #2 PHP_VERSION_ID example and usage

Comment: Where do you get that version string from? Maybe you're just looking for the `PHP_VERSION`, `PHP_MAJOR_VERSION`, `PHP_MINOR_VERSION` constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$subject = '5.4.10-1ubuntu3'; 
$matches = array();
$pattern = '#[0-9]{1,1}.[0-9]{1,2}#';
if (preg_match ($pattern , $subject, $matches) == 1) {
    print "Major version : " . $matches[0] ;
}else {
    print "Can not found version";
}
```